# In Magento how do I get the listing of categories in the order you see in the admin area?

Tags: magento

I can get a list of the children categories for a specific category with the following code:

```
public function displaycats($data, $begin,$end, $catid){
    $currentCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($data[0]);
    $children = explode(",",$currentCat->getChildren());

    foreach ($children as $child) {
    $cot++;
    $subCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child);

        if ($cot >= $begin && $cot <= $end){
            echo '<a href="'.$subCat->getUrl().'?stockable=786">'.$subCat->getName()."</a><br>";
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

The problem is that the list is not ordered the same as Magento has the categories ordered in the admin area. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like @Joe Constant's answer, but when I tried it, I was having trouble only getting the first level of child categories, even with `$recursionLevel` set to `0`.  As a workaround, I wrote this function (place it in (local version of) whichever block you need the sorted child collection):

```
public function getChildrenCollection($parentId=false, $sort='ASC', $attribute='position') 
{
  if (empty($parentId) || !is_numeric($parentId)) return false;
  $childrenArray = explode(',',Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId)->getChildren());
  // remove parent id from array in case it gets returned
  if ($key = array_search($parentId, $childrenArray)) {
    unset($childrenArray[$key]);
  } 
  $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $childrenArray))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

  if (!empty($sort)) {
    return $collection->setOrder($attribute, $sort);
  }
  return $collection;           
}
```

Then you can iterate through the collection and do whatever you need like this:

```
foreach (getChildrenCollection($parentCategoryId) as $child) {
  Zend_Debug::dump($child->getData());
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Look at **getCategories** instead.  It has a sorted parameter as well as an option to return as a collection object removing the need to load each category from the database again.

```php
/**
 * Retrieve categories
 *
 * @param integer $parent
 * @param integer $recursionLevel
 * @param boolean|string $sorted
 * @param boolean $asCollection
 * @param boolean $toLoad
 * @return Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection|Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection
 */
public function getCategories($parent, $recursionLevel = 0, $sorted=false, $asCollection=false, $toLoad=true)
```

`

Answer (score 2):

```
    $helper     = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
    $_categories     = $helper->getStoreCategories('path', true, FALSE);
```

If you want to display the category in the following format

category 1

--- sub category 1a

------ sub category 1aa

--- sub category 1b

category 2

---sub category 2a

---sub category 2b

```
    foreach($_categories as $category){
        $level = $category['level'] - 2;
        $pad = str_repeat("---", ($level > 0) ? $level : 0);

        echo $pad . ' ' . $cat['name']);
        echo '<br/>';
    }

    return $categories;
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote something like this to get list of categories (by parentId) sorted like in admin:

```
$subCats = array();
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($parentId, 1, true, true);
foreach ($children as $category)
{
    $subCats[$category->getPosition()] = $category->getId();
}
ksort($subCats);
```